# How to to write subqueries as aliases using the Criteria Api with NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, subquery, criteria-api

hey guys, say I have Entities and mappings like this:

```
public class Episode
{
    Guid Id {get;set;}
    String Title {get;set;}
    List<Group> Groups {get;set;}
}

public class Group
{
    Guid Id {get;set;}
    DateTime PubDate {get;set;}
}

public class EpisodeMap : ClassMap<Episode>
{
    public EpisodeMap()
    {
        //other mappings..
        Map.HasMany(ep => ep.Groups);
    }
}
```

So, basically, an Episode has many Groups. Each Group has a PubDate, and so an Episode has many PubDates.

I'm trying to write a query using the NHibernate Criteria API which lets me query Episodes and Order them by PubDate given that I have a Group Id.

Essentially, how do I write the equivalent Criteria API query for this SQL query:

```
Select 
    e.*, 
    (Select top 1 ReleaseDate From EpisodeGroups where EpisodeFk = e.Id and GroupFk = @GroupId) as myPubDate 
From Episodes e 
Order By myPubDate
```

Please help! cheers guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public DetachedCriteria BuildCriteria(int episodeId, int groupId)
{

    var groupCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Groups>()
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("this.Id", groupId))
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Group.Id", groupId)) 
        .AddOrder(Order.Asc("Group.PubDate"));

    return DetachedCriteria.For<EpisodeGroups>()
               .Add(Restrictions.Eq("this.Id", episodeId))
               .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("this.Groups", groupCriteria)
               .SetMaxResult(1);
}
```

Then you can do something like this...

```
var episodes = _repository.ExectueCriteria<EpisodeGroups>(BuildCriteria(episodeId, groupId))
```

Just as a special consideration, the reason why you would want to eagerly load the Group entity is in case you would like to use LINQ to compare the PUBDATE later on in your business logic as opposed to using a strict detached criteria.

We have found that by eagerly loading the attributes of an entity will reduce the total number of calls to our database.

No guarantees this code works... but it should at least get you started, good luck :)

Comment: + 1 hey timbob, thanks so much. I've been really struggling with the Criteria API, I find it very unintuitive! I'll give this a try and let you know how I go, thanks for the great explanation

Comment: hey timbob, ok, just had a quick look. it's almost there, but you'll notice in my sql sample, only GroupId is a variable. EpisodeId is part of the query...?

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do and how the rest of your entities are mapped, the restrictions ie. (Restrictions.Eq("this.Id", episodeId)) should account for that. I can't remember offhand if you have to add an alias to both Groups and EpisodeGroups to reference their ids. In other words you may not be able to use "this.Id" but rather respectively you would have to use "Group.Id" and "Episode.Id". I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @andy, please note the bounty will NOT be awarded automatically. It's up to you to do that before it expires!

Comment: @andy, too bad, too late. As you did not award the bounty yourself, the system has now awarded half its value according [to some rules](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work). Next time, please ensure you award it yourself!